# Cleaning fraction coefficients with a term with an exponent

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Where am I going wrong?

$$
\begin{align*}
  V &= \dfrac{4}{3} \pi r^3 \text{ for } \pi & \text{Clear the fractions}\\
  \frac{v}{1} &= \frac{4}{3} \frac{\pi}{1}\frac{r}{1}^3&
  \text{LCD=3, Multiply each term by 3}\\
  \frac{v(3)}{1} &= \frac{4(3)}{3} \frac{\pi(3)}{1}\frac{r(3)}{1}^3&
  \text{Reduce with denominator}\\
  v3 &= 4(1) \pi(3) r(3)^3&
\end{align*}
$$

The method I'm trying to replicate is
$$
\begin{align*}
  -\dfrac{16}{9} &= - \dfrac{4}{3}(\dfrac{5}{3}+n)
  & \text{Distribute through the parenthesis}\\
  -\dfrac{16}{9} &= - \dfrac{20}{9} - \dfrac{4}{3}n
  & \text{LCD = 9, multiply with each term}\\
  -\dfrac{16(9)}{9} &= - \dfrac{20(9)}{9} - \dfrac{4(9)}{3}n
  & \text{Reduce 9 with each denominator}\\
  -16(1) &= -20(1) - 4(3)n
  & \text{Multiply out each term}\\
  -16 &= -20 - 12n
  & \text{Focus on subtraction of 20}\\
  4 &= -12n
  & \text{Focus on multiplication by -12}\\
  \dfrac{4}{-12} &= \dfrac{-12n}{-12}
  & \text{Simplify}\\
  -\dfrac{1}{3} &= n
\end{align*}
$$

here the size of the numbers used to multiply each term are different on both sides.

Comment: It should be $3v=4\pi r^3$. When you multiply all fractions by $3$, you are multiplying by three $3$s, so you’re multiplying the right hand side by $27$ and the left hand side by $3$, breaking equality

Comment: You should multiply both sides by $3$, not every term. The reason is that if a side has more terms, you will multiply that side by a greater number.

Comment: Please see the updated question for the method I'm trying to replicate. Please humor me, I'm using it because the book does.

Answer (score 1):

The book multiplies $9$ to both sides of the equality and then use distributive law.

If the initial expression is $a=b+c$, we can multiply by $d$ on both sides and we have

$$ad = d(b+c) = bd+cd$$

If we have $A=BC$, upon multiplying $D$ to both sides, we just have

$$AD=BCD$$

In your context, your $D$ is $3$. You have multiplied the expression by $3$ too many times.

It should just be

$$3V=4\pi r^3$$